# Doctrine parse error, when i update auto generated file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

First, I've generate entity file via doctrine console commands

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import MyBundle annotation --filter=TblMyTable
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle:TblMyTable --no-backup
```

The program working correctly. But when I update this file via any text editor then I give an exception:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\I" in property
MyBundle\Entity\TblMyTable::$myId does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

I've checked encoding and line-end characters on before and after version for entity file. But I did not see any difference!

**My Environment:**

```
    symfony: 3.0.5
    doctrine/orm: 2.5
    doctrine/doctrine-bundle: 1.6
    doctrine/dbal: 2.5.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand, doctrine parser have a bug for "i" character. Because the "i" character's uppercase "I" or "İ".
"i" character is considered unicode. Doctrine parser does not support unicode.

I've fixed this problem using this command on console

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

This command does exactly what work is described in:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do